# How to implement Google Analytics in Angular2?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, google-analytics

I got a problems trying to implement google analytics in angular2.
According to information I found and as example, in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655898/tracking-google-analytics-page-views-in-angular2) it seems pretty easy. But so far I didn't found any example how to do it not from `.html` but from `.ts` instead.

I am trying to make a private method with google analytics and then call it in constructor. Something like that.

```
constructor() {
  this.initializeAnalytics();
}

private initializeAnalytics() {
    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
        i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
        a = s.createElement(o),
                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
        a.async = 1;
        a.src = g;
        m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ...
    ...
}
```

But just placing google analytics code is not working (Error: `supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target`). I probably am doing it in wrong way.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Check also [angulartics2](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2).

Answer (score 7):

This is how I did it.

You need to put the ga code into your index.html.
(do not forget to comment the following line : `//ga('send', 'pageview');)`

Then you need to declare the ga function into your app.component.ts file, after the imports :

```
import { ... } ...;

declare var ga:Function;

@component(...)
```

Then you could subscribe to the route change event in your app.component.ts and send the ga data like this :

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event:Event) => {
    // Send GA tracking on NavigationEnd event. You may wish to add other 
    // logic here too or change which event to work with
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        // When the route is '/', location.path actually returns ''.
        let newRoute = this.location.path() || '/';
        // If the route has changed, send the new route to analytics.
        if (this.currentRoute != newRoute) {
            ga('send', 'pageview', newRoute);
            //console.log('would send to ga: ' + newRoute);
            this.currentRoute = newRoute;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this is exactly the same thing what i found (watch linked url)

Comment: I have got a code like `window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());` unlike `ga('send', 'pageview');)` for index.html. which one to use

Comment: @ThilakRaj the original code is available here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ It looks like they updated their code with something new. I can't figure out how to implement it yet.

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the code to Typescript. Currently it is Javascript. The function at

```
function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m)
```

has 7 non-optional parameters, however you only supply 5 in this line:

```
(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga')
```

You'd need to make the remaining parameters optional like so:

```
function (i, s, o, g, r, a?, m?)
```

You then also need to change a different line from:

```
}, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
```

to

```
}, i[r].l = 1 * <any>new Date();
```

The final code could look like this:

```
(function (i, s, o, g, r, a?, m?) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * <any>new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
```