# How to track events in Google Analytics with Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, google-analytics

I've implemented this solution for page tracking in Google Analytics with Angular2 https://stackoverflow.com/a/39622860/4155124 and it works well.

How could I use

```
            ga('send', {
                hitType: 'event',
                eventCategory: 'Some Category',
                eventAction: 'Level Completed',
                eventLabel: 'Level 3'
            });
```

within a component?

This code works within the component but there is a "cannot find ga" error in the console.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can either download the real definition file (links below) **or** you can make your own definition file **or** simply type:

```
declare var ga: any;
```

at the top of your code like the OP did in the link you provided (but this way it won't autocomplete the `ga` methods).

**Update:**

Since typescript is moving from `typings` to `@types` the new repo is: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google.analytics

you can install the d.ts files via: `npm install --save @types/google.analytics`

If you are using angular-cli here's the tutorial for making it work with 3rd party libraries: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib

Comment: I tried to use the type definition of Google Analytics, but their defined methods were not the Google Analytics (analytics.js) have. like, `ga('send')`

Comment: @M98 hmm it might be a different or deprecated library

Comment: 404 at given link