# How to include Google Analytics in Angular Cli application

Tags: angular, google-analytics, angular-cli

Usually including analytics was about pasting their tracking code in the html body, with the property Id and the pageview action. I followed the answer in
[Tracking Google Analytics Page Views in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655898/tracking-google-analytics-page-views-in-angular2) and when doing `ng serve` it includes correctly the script but then when generating production aot it is not included in the index:

```
ng build --progress false --aot true -prod -e prod
```

What is the best practice to include Google Analytics or other tracking solution with Angular2 Cli?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Following the suggestion in the Angular Cli project, it is need to put the script outside the app-root, I included in the head https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4451#issuecomment-281628623

Comment: Is that okay if the code is added to an external .js file and linked through .angular-cli.json ?

Answer (score 7):

You can bundle it with the rest of your scripts using Angular-CLI.

Put the google analytics code in a file named something like `google-analytics.js`. Make sure you remove the script tags.

Then in your `angular-cli.json` file, add your `google-analytics.js`file to the `scripts` property.

Here is an example of what the code would look like in `angular-cli.json`.

```
"scripts": [
    "google-analytics.js"
],
```

This snippet will cause angular-cli to bundle google-analytics into a file named `scripts.bundle.js` which is loaded at run-time with the `ng serve` command.

Comment: but how are you loading it only for production?

Comment: And how can you change the tracking ID if you're deploying to test/acc/prod ?

Comment: A workaround can be using several apps in .angular-cli.json file ( https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-apps ) . Dev app includes file google-analytics.dev.js and Prod app includes google-analytics.prod.js.

Comment: @vlio20 - Using build config options we can add an additional script for that particular environment also - atleast in Angular 7.

Comment: angular aot build not working for google analytics, Can u pls help to me

Answer (score 3):

Angular Version 7: One way to include some js which is environment-specific is to

1. save the script at some path: E.g: `src/assets/javascripts/google_analytics.js`
2. Then in `angular.json` find the build config for the specific config (Ref: [here](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#build-configs)) and in the desired environment add an additional scripts array.
3. `ng build --prod` will additionally bundle the extra script also. (whatever environment the additional script is added to taking prod for example here)

Below sample uses the production environment for demonstration but this can be done for any environment.

Sample angular.json below. Tested on Angular 7 (Please only refer to the "scripts" key inside the build config, file is heavily modified to show only the relevant part)

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "test": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {},
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "scripts": ["src/assets/javascripts/google_analytics.js"]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "test"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In angular-cli project you can do it in `main.ts` - e.g. here we add GA only for production build

```js
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {

    let ga_id = "UA-123456789-1" // google analytics id
    
    document.write(`<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${ga_id}"></script>`);

    const script1 = document.createElement('script');
    script1.innerHTML = `

        // Google Analytics

        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());
            gtag('config', '${ga_id}', {
            'linker': {
            'domains': ['your-domain.com']
            }
        });
    `;
    document.head.appendChild(script1);

    enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

The `environment.prod.ts` must contains field `production: true`:

```js
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  loginApi: 'https://my-api./v1',
};
```

Comment: this does not work for me when running `ng serve --configuration=production`

Comment: @chris - you are right-  I forgot to mention that environment files must contains field `production = true` - answer updated

Comment: Not working for me, js console gives "A call to document.write() from an asynchronously-loaded external script was ignored."

Comment: @kostas.kougios instead `documet.write(...)`try `document.head.innerHTML+=...` (you can also combine it with `setTimeout(...)` )