# Angulartics2 - Multiple Route Files + Google Analytics

Tags: angular, angulartics2

When implementing Angulartics2 in my Angular application I get Google Tracking for the initial page view to work, and anytime I refresh the page (hard refresh) Google Analytics picks up the new page view to track as well.

The problem occurring is that when I go from one route to another without refreshing the application, Google Analytics live tracker doesn't detect the user is on a new page.

```
imports: [
    ...,
    Angulartics2Module.forRoot([Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics], {
            pageTracking: {
                clearIds: true,
                clearQueryParams: true,
            }
        })
]
```

Has anyone experienced this or know what could be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with the "newer" gtag setup for GA.  I was able to get it to work properly using the older method here
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/

Just make sure you remove that initial
`ga('send', 'pageview')`

as mentioned here
[Tracking Google Analytics Page Views in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655898/tracking-google-analytics-page-views-in-angular2?rq=1)